# What does `upstream/HEAD -> upstream/master` means in `git branch -r`

Tags: git

In the list of my remotes I see: (`git branch -r`)

```
upstream/HEAD -> upstream/master
```

Of course I have a `upstream/master`, and origin is my fork on the main repo (which is upstream).

So what does that `upstream/HEAD` means? (it's probably some sort of alias) And why is it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{remote}/HEAD` is the default branch for that remote.

If you clone from that remote URL, it's the branch that is checked out automatically if you don't specify a different branch.

Comment: It's also how Git resolves the name `upstream` (or whatever the remote name is) in the absence of a `/specific-remote-tracking-branch` part. OP should see both `gitrevisions` and `git remote` documentation (specifically the section on `git remote set-head`).

Comment: Nice thanks! I just did it for my other remotes :) `git remote set-head origin master` gives `origin/HEAD -> origin/master`, etc.